# Issue with Docker Volumes in Preserving Nexus Data

Tags: docker, nexus, nexus3, volumes

I'm encountering a problem with Docker volumes while attempting to preserve Nexus data within a container

I have a Docker image containing Maven and npm artifacts, with all the data stored in the /nexus-data directory. On a remote machine, I've set up a Nexus container and published all Maven and npm artifacts. Then, I'm using a script to create an image with this data, as described in the provided Dockerfile.

```
# Use the official Nexus base image
FROM sonatype/nexus3

# Copy the Nexus data from the host to the container's data directory
COPY nexus-data /nexus-data

# Change permission 
USER root
RUN chown -R nexus:nexus /nexus-data
USER nexus

# Set the desired permissions on the Nexus data directory
COPY --chown=nexus:nexus nexus-data /nexus-data

# Start Nexus on port 8079
EXPOSE 8079

# Start Nexus
CMD ["sh", "-c", "/opt/sonatype/start-nexus-repository-manager.sh"]
```

However, when I try to use bind volumes to preserve the Nexus data, it doesn't work as expected. The data doesn't persist, and it seems like the container starts fresh without any data. Here's the command I'm using:

```
mkdir /data
chown -R 200:200 /data
docker run -d -p 8081:8081 -v /data:/nexus-data <image>
```

When I am not using any data volumes in container creation, it is working as expected.

I have read somewhere that if the host machines volume directory is empty, it will overrides the container's data. But I needs to use the data volumes as my nexus image will be recreates very often.

I expected the Nexus data to be preserved and accessible within the container when using bind volumes.

Comment: You can't both have the data in an image and also a volume.  Can you copy the data to the host's `/data` directory, and run the unmodified `sonatype/nexus3` with the bind mount?  (Why do you want the data to be in the image?)

Comment: @David, Our platform architecture involves generating data on a build machine and shipping it to other machines using Docker images. We need the data bundled within the image for shipping but also require flexibility to access and modify it on different machines. This preserves the data within the image for shipping and allows us to access and manipulate it across different machines

Comment: If you're using a host directory to store the content, can you share (a tar file of) the directory, instead of trying to embed it in a Docker image?

Comment: There in some of my machines, there will not be internet access, so need to it is the only way that my higher authorities recommended to do by embedding inside the docker image